# Convexity of the product of two functions in higher dimensions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Exercise 3.32 page 119 of [Convex Optimization](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) is concerned with the proof that if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto f(x)$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto g(x)$ are both convex, nondecreasing (or nonincreasing) and positive, then $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ is also convex.

Are there any generalisations or analogies of this claim to the case where both $f$ and $g$ are convex functions mapping elements from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, for any $n>1$?

Comment: Why is it necessary that $f,g$ be monotonous?

Comment: @becko The statement is not true if we drop monotonicity. For instance, let $f=(|x|+10^{-6})_{x\in\mathbb R},g=(e^{-x})_{x\in\mathbb R};$ then $fg=((|x|+10^{-6})\cdot e^{-x})_{x\in\mathbb R}$ is not convex. (For instance, $f(0)=10^{-6},f(1)=1.000001/e,f(2)=2.000002/e^2<1.000001/e$ since $2/e<1,$ so $f(0),f(2)<f(1),$ so $f$ is not quasiconvex and hence is not convex.)

Comment: See also Exercise 10(g), page 204, in Stromberg's *An Introduction to Classical Real Analysis* (AMS, 2015), or Exercise 10(g), page 204, in Stromberg's *Introduction to Classical Real Analysis* (Wadsworth, 1981). This book has lots of exercises, by the way.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes a generalization is possible. Here is an elementary approach to the convexity of the product of two nonnegative convex functions defined on a convex domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Choose $x$ and $y$ in the domain and $t$ in $[0,1]$. Your aim is to prove that $\Delta\ge0$ with
$$\Delta=t(fg)(x)+(1-t)(fg)(y)-(fg)(tx+(1-t)y).
$$
But $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative and convex, hence
$$
(fg)(tx+(1-t)y)\le(tf(x)+(1-t)f(y))(tg(x)+(1-t)g(y)).
$$
Using this and some easy algebraic manipulations, one sees that $\Delta\ge t(1-t)D(x,y)$ with
$$
D(x,y)=f(x)g(x)+f(y)g(y)-f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x),
$$
that is,
$$
D(x,y)=(f(x)-f(y))(g(x)-g(y)).
$$
This proves a generalization of the result you quoted to any product of convex nonnegative functions $f$ and $g$ such that $D(x,y)\ge0$ for every $x$ and $y$ in the domain of $f$ and $g$.

In particular, if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at a point $x$ in the domain, one asks that their gradients $\nabla f(x)$ and $\nabla g(x)$ are such that $z^*M(x)z\ge0$ for every $n\times 1$ vector $z$, where $M(x)$ is the $n\times n$ matrix
$$
M(x)=\nabla f(x)\cdot(\nabla g(x))^*.
$$

Comment: If one were willing to consider smooth functions, the derivative version of this statement _may_ make the mechanism easier to understand (depends on one's point of view, of course).

Comment: @Willie If $f$ is not differentiable at $x$, replace the gradient of $f$ at $x$ by any subgradient of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and all the details!