# Convexity of the product of two functions defined on two different sets

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

So I have two nonnegative convex functions $f_a:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f_b:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined on the convex sets $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^a$ and $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^b$.

If I consider their product, i.e. $f:\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(a, b) = f_a(a) f_b(b)$, is this function convex? First of all, I should show that $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}$ is convex, but this is strightforward. Then, I have to show the convexity of $f$.

This is what I tried so far: Consider $a_1, a_2 \in \mathcal{A}$ and $b_1, b_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$. I have to show that
$$f(\lambda a_1 + (1-\lambda) a_2, \lambda b_1 + (1-\lambda) b_2) \leq \lambda f(a_1, b_1) + (1-\lambda) f(a_2, b_2)$$
Expanding the LHS and applying the convexity of $f_a$ and $f_b$, I get
$$f(\lambda a_1 + (1-\lambda) a_2, \lambda b_1 + (1-\lambda) b_2) \leq \lambda^2 f(a_1, b_1) + (1-\lambda)^2 f(a_2, b_2) + \lambda(1-\lambda) \left[ f_a(a_1)f_b(b_2) + f_a(a_2)f_b(b_1) \right]$$

Now $\lambda^2 \leq \lambda$ and $(1-\lambda)^2 \leq (1-\lambda)$, but I don't know how to get rid of the mixed terms.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple counter example is, take $f_a , f_b$ identity functions on $R$.

then $f(x,y)= xy $,  which is clearly not a convex function.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. What additional assumption should I put on the functions? Or, maybe I should say: are there situations in which this statement is true?

Comment: @AndreaCamisa  I don't know. The hessian of $f$ must be Positive definite , maybe you could get something from it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the statement that *product of convex functions are convex* is false.

<del>Consider the following case for $x\in \mathbb{R}$:

$f_{a}(x) = (x-2)^{2}$, $f_{b}(x) = (x+2)^{2}$

Then, $f(a,b) = f_{a}f_{b}(x) = (x-2)^{2}(x+2)^{2}$ is clearly *non-convex*. [I can't post images yet but I wanted to show a plot in Wolfram Alpha][1]</del>

It is, however, possible to impose constraints on your convex functions to make their product convex (e.g. both non-decreasing/increasing in addition to non-negativity). Please refer to [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27571/convexity-of-the-product-of-two-functions-in-higher-dimensions) for more details.

#### EDIT

As comment correctly pointed out, $f(a,b) = f_{a}(x)f_{b}(x) \neq f_{a}f_{b}(x)$. Therefore the product should be 
$f(a,b) = f_{a}(x)f_{b}(y) = (x-2)^2 (y+2)^2$ which is still non-convex.

Comment: This is not a product of two convex functions !!  variables are separate!
 It's just a two_variable  function. But still f(a,b) is not necessarily convex, see my counter example.

Comment: @Redshoes good catch! Apologies for the silly mistake.