# Why is $f(x)g(x)$ a convex in $[a,b]$,when $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both convex and positive in $x \in [a,b ]$?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Two non-increasing convex functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are positive in $x \in [a,b ]$ , then  f(x)g(x)  is convex in $[a,b] $ Does anyone know how to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$(f(x)g(x))'' = f''(x)g(x)+2f'(x)g'(x)+f(x)g''(x) \ge 0.$$

Comment: How do you show this when $f$ and $g$ aren't (twice) differentiable?

Comment: @TheoBendit https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27571/convexity-of-the-product-of-two-functions-in-higher-dimensions